# autoincrement and text in rt index in Sphinx

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I was able to use sphinx rt index successfully but I have two issues though. 
The first one is how to use autoincrement in rt index for the ID?

The second one is how to get the text field? the documentation says "you should explicitly enumerate all the text fields", I'm not sure how to do that?
I'm using PHP to query the rt index and I can see the result except for the text fields, I'm using the same index in the sphinx doc.

```
index rt
{
    type = rt
    path = /usr/local/sphinx/data/rt
    rt_field = title
    rt_field = content
    rt_attr_uint = gid
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx doesnt have "autoincrement" ids. You could run a query to find the max id, and then add one. but its not 'safe' if have multiple clients inserting. There is no lock index.

Fields are not stored in the index. So you CAN'T get them back out. They are tokenized and indexed, but not stored.

The 'enumerate' comment, is that you need to list all fields in the index definition. (unlike disk indexes, which will automatically make a column a field, if its not defined as an attribute. )

Attributes on the other hand ARE stored, and can be retrieved. If want to be able to make a column searchable, and retrieveable, need to insert it twice, once as a field, then again as an attribute.

(Note sphinx is not really intended to be a 'database' - but rather just an index to one. So it designed around the case that its 'mirroring' the data)

Comment: Thanks, so how can I use the rt index then if I can't get the test? do I need to save the text in a DB and put the id of it in the rt index and retrieve it after getting the result of the query to the index?

Comment: `Sphinx doesnt have "autoincrement" ids. You could run a query to find the max id, and then add one. but its not 'safe' if have multiple clients inserting. There is no lock index.` What's the solution, then? How do you know what ID to pass when inserting new records?

Comment: The idea really is that you've already inserted the data into a 'real' database. By the time the data is inserted into Sphinx you already have a unique ID assigned. Sphinx is meant to be a 'index' to an existing database, rather than holding the actual authortive database.